# Animation with Latex Beamer

Tags: beamer, animations

I'd like to produce a sort of animation effect in my presentation.

I have an image:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{./images/avatar-landscape.jpg}
\end{figure}
```

and many bullets describing it:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item This is the first bullet item of the slide
\item This is the second bullet item of the slide
\item This is the third bullet item of the slide
\end{itemize}
```

Unfortunately the image is very big, and both elements do not fit in a single frame. Therefore I wanted to add a sort of animation in which I have the following visual effect:

[image]

And going to the next slide should maintain the image but skip to the next bullet of the list I posted before.

I surely can imagine of a simple way to do it (adding a number of frames for each bullet item with the same figure), but was wondering if there was some particular way to produce such an effect without increasing the number of frames (which would avoid the number of page to increase).

Can you help me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want a non moving `itemize` right? Well try the `dosomething@slide` syntax:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{
 \begin{figure}\centering
  \rule{10cm}{8cm}
 \end{figure}
  \begin{itemize}[<only@+>]
  \item This is the first bullet item of the slide
  \item This is the second bullet item of the slide
  \item This is the third bullet item of the slide
\end{itemize}

}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Providing that i got you right this is exactly what you want. 
Basically this `@` Syntax says do action at slide, were `+`  means next slide always. See also the beamer manual.

Comment: you got it right, and it's all clear to me now!thks a lot...

Comment: Thank you for this great example. It expanded my knowledge for the subject of facetting quite a bit. When I run this code, i have a slight jump of the black box between the first and the second frame. Why is that? Adding a % in the figure code does not change it ...

Answer (score 3):

The following does what you want although it is not an animation *per se* but involves designing th esequence on a single slide:

```
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{4cm}
  \only<1>{First slide text.}
  \only<2>{Text for the first slide.\\This can be several lines long.}
  \only<3>{Third slide text, almost as long.}
\end{overlayarea}
```

The Beamer manusl gives examples and also a few additional examples

Comment: should I use this code in place of the `itemize` environment?